# Objective-C: Status bar hides when I create the window programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, window, statusbar, appdelegate

I am trying to create window programmatically in App delegate, but status bar hides. In info.plist it is is not set to YES. The app is perfectly working in this way, but I need to show status bar too.
I have window and navigationController property in AppDelegate.h 
here is my didFinishLaunch

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//even when I used customized CGRect and used it initWithFrame, there is no status bar
self.navigationController = [[IEENavigationController alloc] init];
XYZViewController *homeViewController = [[XYZViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"XYZViewController"  bundle:nil];
[navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could add this in the info.plist:

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance - YES
```

then add this method in the view controllers you want to hide the status bar.

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }
```

Comment: In info.plist is UIStatusBarHidden set to YES?

Comment: No it is NO, Status Bar is initially hidden is set to NO too.